# Correct word for "Pulling some one into work, with continuous effort"?

Tags: word-choice

Please consider the below excerpt.

> 'How long is your break?' I shouted. A group of labourers sat under the banyan tree near the main campus building. 'It's two-thirty, lunch ended an hour ago'
>   The workers tightened their turbans. They picked up their brushes and moved to the classrooms, I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of ***_*__*_*__*_*** up the men every two hours.

I need some help to figure it out correct word to fill the blank among the below set of words. I am giving words along with their meanings those I have found in Oxford English Dictionary. How different word changes if I use one instead another?

> **haul** = (of a person) pull or drag with effort or force.
>   **Drag** = pull (someone or something) along forcefully, roughly, or with difficult.

Comment: @Fortiter: THanks for your answers. My question is how the meaning of the sentence changes if I use on of the other word.

Comment: The fact that the answers suggested do not use one of your options suggests that NEITHER is appropriate for placing before "up" in your sample sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the two words you have selected are appropriate in the context you are using them in.

Are you physically having to drag or pull the men back to work? If so, either of those words would work, but **only** if you are physically dragging them back to work.

You'll notice in your word meanings, both say *haul a person* or *pull someone* they can only be used if you are physically pulling a person.

In your sample text you suggest that you are *verbally* encouraging them back to work, *('How long is your break?' I shouted.)* if that is the case then *chivvy* would be a better word to use -

From OED -

> chivvy, v.1
>
> To harry, harass, trouble, worry.

In use -

> Doris..and I chivvied the chicken around till we caught her.
>
> ...exhausted by my daily ritual of *chivvying* up the men every two hours.

The word *up* is not strictly necessary and would work with or without it.

Comment: +1 for getting right to the problem, **and** explaining word choice through commonly-accepted usage.

Answer (score 1):

1) I rather like "herding the cats." The idea is that cats are very independent and don't take well to being told what to do, and will scatter and go their own way if forced. You can herd cattle, sheep, or horses because they are group animals which naturally follow a leader and respond to goading from behind.

> I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of herding the cats every two hours.

2) just use "rounding."

> I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of rounding up the men every two hours.

3) Extend the cattle/sheep/horse image.

> I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of rounding up the men and corralling them back to work every two hours.

Comment: +1 for detailing the character behaviour that could determine the choice of phrase.

Answer (score 1):

> I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of **dragooning** the men every two hours.

Although a dragoon was originally a member of a heavy cavalry unit, the use of such forces to impose the will of a conqueror on unwilling people led to the use of *dragooning* to mean "demanding compliance by threat or coercion".

In recent times, the meaning has softened as it was used for exaggerated effect. "I was dragooned into helping with the childrens' bath time."

In that sense, it is suitable for your case where there is certainly a lack of cooperation but the resistance is passive.

Comment: ooh, I like yours better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

> The workers tightened their turbans. They picked up their brushes and moved to the classrooms, I remained under the banyan tree, exhausted by my daily ritual of **marshalling** <strike>up</strike> the men every two hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
rounding up
assembling
collecting
dragooning
gathering
mustering
marshalling
corraling, herding, driving
```

I think "dragoon" is a wonderfully descriptive term, and has the sense of forcing someone to do service that many of the other terms lack (though supplied here by context in the passage). I don't know how many people would understand it today, but it'd probably be my first choice as well.

I don't think "marshal" fits quite as well as some other choices.

If the word "up" must remain, I favor "collecting", "gathering", "mustering", and "corralling" the best.  I don't think either "hauling up" or "dragging up" fits well at all.